# Rails' datetime and timestamp in a migration file are the same for MySQL and Sqlite3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, migration, timestamp

`:datetime` and `:timestamp` in a migration file seems like the same in MySQL and Sqlite3, and they both map to `datetime` in the database side, except I can't find that in a formal documentation.

Also, what about when if our Rails project may use other DBMS, then should we use `:datetime` or `:timestamp` when we `script/generate` (or `rails generate`) our Model or Scaffold?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I would recommend using the `:datetime`, because so it's clear what to use. I believe rails is using `DATETIME` for both in the DB is because of the Problem that the datetimes representable with the unix timestamp or the MySQL `TIMESTAMP` field. Since timestamp is by default a 32bit Integer (see [Wikipedia:Timestamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time#Representing_the_number)) it can only represent dates between `1901-12-13` (or `1970-01-01` if no negative values are allowed like in [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html)) and `2038-01-19`. After or before that it will overflow. This is the [year 2038 problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem).

So to make it clear to everybody I would name it `:datetime` in the migration.

> The TIMESTAMP data type has a range of '1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC to '2038-01-19 03:14:07' UTC. It has varying properties, depending on the MySQL version and the SQL mode the server is running in. These properties are described later in this section. [Source](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html)

Comment: Thanks @jigfox for this useful information. I'm wondering to know that Rails uses `created_at` and `updated_at` as `timestamp`. Shouldn't it be `datetime` as `timestamp` will create problem after 19th Jan, 2038?